# Calculate jump height only with 'time in air"

Tags: math, height, physics

How to calculate jump height having only time in air.

It is possible to calculate jump height when i have only time "in air"? Time starts when my shoes/feets lose contact to floor and stop when touch it again (approximately). Half of all time my body will rise up and half of time fall down. It is correct? Both movements accelerations will be earth acceleration ~9,8 m/s^2? Is my thinking ok?
So after half of time my body will be in top point and my velocity will be 0 m/s. Next half of time i will fall down with acceleration ~9,8  m/s^2. For example:
When total time of jump = 0.6s => rise up time = fall down time = 0.3s.
s = (a * t^2) / 2 =  0.441m.
Has this sense :D?
s = (9.8 * 0.3^2) / 2
s = (9.8 * 0.09) / 2 =

Comment: This is a mathematics problem, not a programming problem. Try https://math.stackexchange.com/ (search first, post later) and you get the chance for proper math formatting as a bonus.

Comment: @MvG It's physics. There's https://physics.stackexchange.com . Having a question closed on one of the countless sites and being asked to repost it at another wrong site can be reaaaaaaally frustrating. Also it's better to migrate the question than close it and ask to repost it on another site!

Comment: Your calculation is correct but 0.441m is a bit too precise. If there is an error `e` on the total time in the air, i.e. if the total time in the air is `t + e`, then the error on the result will be `g t e / 2`. For instance if the time in the air is `0.6 ± 0.1 s`, then the height of the jump will be `0.441 ± 0.147 m`

Comment: @Stef Of course time in air has error. But i will measure it with diy platform with tensometers so time will be quite precise. With tensometers i can measure weight but popular set of tensometers can handle max 200kg so i think it is too little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration is `g`, pointing downwards. Calling `y(t)` the height at time `t`:

```
y''(t) = -g
y'(t) = -g t + c0
y(t) = -g t² / 2 + c0 t + c1
```

We can find `c0` and `c1` using the initial conditions:

```
y(0)   = 0
y'(t1) = 0      where t1 = 0.3 seconds
```

Thus:

```
y(0) = c1 = 0

y'(t1) = -g t1 + c0 = 0
c0 = g t1
```

Substituting `c1 = 0` and `c0 = g t1`:

```
y(t) = - g t² / 2 + g t1 t
     = g t (t1 - t/2)
```

Finally we can find the height reached at time t1 = 0.3 seconds:

```
y(t1) = g t1 (t1 - t1 / 2)
      = g t1² / 2
      = 9.8 × 0.3² / 2
      = 0.4 m
```

If you jump for 0.6 seconds, then you will jump at a height of 0.4 m.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law:

```
F = ma
```

We know that `F = -mg` and `a = y''`.

Therefore:

```
y''(t) = -g
```

We can integrate twice to get `y(t)`:

```
y'(t) = -g*t + c0
```

and

```
y(t) = -g*t^2/2 + c0*t + c1
```

We know the initial height and velocity:

```
y(0) = c1 = 0
```

and

```
y'(0) = c0 = v0
```

So

```
y(t) = -g*t^2/2 + v0*t = t*(v0 - g*t/2)
```

The height `y = 0` when `t = 0` and when `t = 2*v0/g`.

The max height occurs when the velocity is zero:

```
y'(t) = 0 = g*t_ymax - v0
```

Solving for t_ymax:

```
t_ymax = v0/g
```

The time when you reach the max height is exactly half the time it takes to leave the ground and return.  If you can measure the total time to jump and return to the ground you can calculate v0:

```
v0 = t_ymax*g
```

We can rewrite the formula for y(t):

```
y(t) = t*g(t_ymax - t/2)
```

I'm betting that Michael Jordan has a higher initial velocity than I do.  That's why his hang time is so much better than mine.

This is physics and calculus that I learned in high school.  Not difficult.

Thanks to Stef for the correction.

Comment: I disagree with `y'(0) = c0 = 0`. This is a human jumping. There is an initial velocity in the upwards direction when the human pushes off the ground, although its exact value is unknown. You have to deduce its value by using the fact that y' is 0 at t=3 seconds, or that y is 0 at t=6 seconds.

Comment: Your approximation is that the human did not jump and stayed on the ground! This contradicts the information we have that the jump lasted exactly 6 seconds.

Comment: You do realise the solution you give at the end is negative? You end up with `ymax = -g*tair^2/8 < 0`. Don't you see a contradiction there? It's not that I don't like your answer. Everything in your answer is correct, except the claim that `y'(0) = c0 = 0
`. And starting from this false claim, all the calculations that follow are false.

Comment: You are correct, Stef.  My first effort was hasty and poor.  I valued a simple, wrong formula too much. 
 Thank you for the correction.

Comment: The formula was correct :) It's just the initial condition y'(0) = 0 which was false. By using this initial condition you were solving for the problem where the human just "falls" without jumping. As if the ground disappears at t=0. Which is why the result you got was negative: if the human doesn't jump and the ground disappears, then the human falls below the ground.

Comment: @duffymo so you write the same as me :D. What is "y" in your formulas? Is it distance? And what is "tair"?

Comment: @goliat26 `y` is height, and `tair` is `t_{air} = "time in the air" = 0.6 seconds`. There is no need for horizontal distance: if you jump vertically, the horizontal distance is zero.

Comment: @Stef yes i mean distance in vertical :). Thanks. Ok so my first thinking about this calculations was correct. I skip all of derivation of the formula but results was OK. Thanks for explanations for all :)